# Wayland NVidia Starting Problems

Tags: drivers, nvidia, skype, acer, wayland

I installed the latest version of ubuntu yesterday. 18.10.
Now my computer (Acer Aspire F15) won't work as before anymore. In a normal ubuntu session after entering my password i just get to the same profile again asking me to enter my password (after a black screen with a frozen mouse pointer for ca. 5 seconds).
Logging in with Wayland is possible, but nothing really works there. Opening more then 3 programs leads to a crash and ends all processes and logs me out. (Terminal, MeetFranz, Skype). Anyway Skype doesn't work at all anymore. in the system log i don't see any operation after attempting to open skype. Does anyone else have that issue? I get the notification in my system logs though:

```
kernel: i2c_hid i2c-ELAN0501:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (14/65535)
```

I changed the drivers to the integrated intel drivers, it did not make a difference. is it related to the code? What can I do about it?

Comment: About a month ago, on my laptop with Nvidia, Wayland started to be offered, and if selected, switched video from Nvida to the integrated (i915) -- no problems noted.  You're not using bumlebee are you?  That might mess things up.

Comment: @ubfan1 No, I didn't use bumlebee. I also switched to the integraded drivers, but it didn't make any difference in the behaviour. The weird kind of crash on wayland and the impossible log in in the normal mode.